# cdk deploy deletes the bootstrap version ssm parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, aws-ssm

Here's how I'm instantiating my stack:

```
new LambdaStack(new App(), 'LambdaStack', {
    env: { account: AWS_ACCOUNT_ID, region: 'us-east-1' },
    synthesizer: new DefaultStackSynthesizer({
        qualifier: 'lambda-stk',
    }),
    stackName: 'LambdaStack',
});
```

First I ensure that my `~/.aws/credentials` file has the correct credentials. Then I bootstrap:

`npx cdk bootstrap --qualifier lambda-stk --toolkit-stack-name LambdaStack aws://ACCOUNT_ID_HERE/us-east-1`

Everything looks good in the console. Then, I deploy:

`npx cdk deploy --require-approval never`

Everything still looks good in the console -- the lambdas have been created as I expected, etc.

Then, I simply run the same deploy command again without changing anything and I get this error:

```
LambdaStack failed: Error: LambdaStack: SSM parameter /cdk-bootstrap/lambda-stk/version not found. Has the environment been bootstrapped? Please run 'cdk bootstrap' (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/bootstrapping.html)
```

Upon further investigation, it seems that the bootstrap command properly creates the referenced SSM parameter but then the first deploy command deletes that parameter. Why would it do that and how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Problems can arise when you rename the tool kit. try to remove --toolkit-stack-name and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by naming the bootstrap stack something different from `LambdaStack`. I was under the impression that the bootstrap command was spinning up the stack that the "main" stack would use, but actually it's a completely different stack. So I changed the bootstrap command to:

`npx cdk bootstrap --qualifier lambda-stk --toolkit-stack-name LambdaStackCDKToolkit aws://ACCOUNT_ID_HERE/us-east-1`

And it worked.

Comment: Why did you need to change the name of the stack at all? The Bootstrap stack is used by all CDK applications you deploy, not just by your lambda stack.

Comment: I have cdk setups in different repos -- I separate by logic instead of having the entire stack setup in one "monolith" repo

Comment: There should still be a single bootstrap stack per environment, shared across all CDK apps.

Comment: For clarity for those reading this in the future, a reason you might want a per-project CDK bootstrap: the default execution role created by the CDK bootstrap stack(s) has admin permissions so if you want to create strict boundaries across projects or teams, you can spin up different CDK stacks using custom policies for the execution role as described here: https://betterdev.blog/cdk-bootstrap-least-deployment-privilege/